# Protractor-Cucumber Promises Best Practices

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, protractor, cucumber

In the test project, basically I have steps to do the relation feature-page object. I know that the functions in page objects should return promise but I don't know the most elegant way to do it.
Now the flow of my code is:

1. Step definition have the call to the page object function( my exemple: testPage.insertCredentials(user))
2. In the function insertCredentials of testPage, I do the logic and finally I return the last line because I need to return something to the stepTest.js as the function of step is waiting the promise to execute callback.
3. Execute callback, and the flow of step should be continue.

stepTest.js

```
 module.exports = function(){
 [...] 
   this.When(/^I insert valid credentials "([^"]*)"$/, function (user, callback) {
      testPage.insertCredentials(user).then(function(){
         callback();
      });
   });
 [...]
 }
```

testPage.js

```
var testPage = {
   insertCredentials: function insertCredentials(usuario){
     userInput: element(by.id('user')),
     passInput: element(by.id('password')),
     [...]
     var user = 'test';
     var password = 'testpass';
     // input user and password
     testPage.userInput.sendKeys(user);
     return testPage.passInput.sendKeys(password);

   }
}
module.exports=loginPage;
```

Thank's :)